# After subclassing, how can I override the parent's constructor while still using it?

Tags: php, oop

Example: I have a class called ParentClass. ParentClass has a constructor like this:

```
function __construct($tpl) {
    // do something with the $tpl
}
```

When creating a new instance of ParentClass, I must provide that $tpl parameter like this:

```
$p = new ParentClass('index');
```

Then there's a ChildClass extends ParentClass. I want that the constructor of ChildClass provides that $tpl to ParentClass, but of course I don't want just an instance of ParentClass, but of ChildClass.

So when creating a new ChildClass instance, I want it to look like:

```
$foo = new ChildClass();
```

But internally, I want it to provide that 'index' to the constructor of ParentClass.

How can I achieve that in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `parent::__construct()` you can call the constructor of the [parent](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
  function __construct($tpl) {
    parent::__construct($tpl);
  }
}
```

Now create the instance of childclass:

```
$p = new ChildClass('index');
```

> **Note:** In your child class, you should
>   include the parent class.

Comment: Thanks! What I want to achieve is that I don't have to provide 'index' anymore with using ChildClass. That's the whole point of ChildClass :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `parent::_construct('index');` from within the `ChildClass` constructor. This will construct the base class using `index`.